# How to get a custom date format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need help in Excel to figure out how to get the following date format:

> Mon, 9-Jan-2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a date (but the wrong format)

- format → cells → user defined: `DDD, D-MMM-YYYY`

If you want the current date in your desired format

- enter this formula: `=TEXT(NOW(),"DDD, D-MMM-YYYY")`
- you can replace NOW() with cell references like [A1] if this cell already have a valid date

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, using Today as the date in question.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd"),", ",TEXT(TODAY(),"d-mmm-yyyy"))
```