# excel requires one date format for cell entry but shows another

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, date

In Excel (2023) for Mac  I have formatted a few fields as Date dd.m.yy. And it displays the dates in those cells as such.

BUT, it requires me to enter the date with the format m/dd/yy.

So I prefer to be able to enter the date as shown and not in another way. How can I do it?

Thank you.

[Excel settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFCEk.png)

[Mac settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y0Rx.png)

Comment: Regardless of how they are displayed them, dates have to be entered using the locale setting.  That's a control panel thing in Windows, but I don't know where Excel gets it on the Mac.

Comment: At least historically, Excel had it's own "locale settings" (i.e. in which format(?) to enter and display dates per default), it was a long time since I last had a look though. Nowadays always expecting locale to be used... i.e. Region & Language in Control Panel on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set date format when manually inserting date on excel, without changing regional settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/925087/how-to-set-date-format-when-manually-inserting-date-on-excel-without-changing-r)

Comment: None of the above solves the problem. Both in Mac settings and in excel settings the format is dd.mm.yyyy as you can see from the pictured added.